# How do I display velocity vectors of different pixels of an image over the image?

Tags: java, image-processing, charts, graph

How do I display velocity vectors of different pixels of an image over the image?

I have an array of vectors( vx and vy for each pixel). I want to display velocity vectors(by arrows of corresponding magnitude and direction). I need to know how to use the velocity vector data( 2 arrays vx and vy) to a graph/chart/image showing arrows. This is part of work to display the output of optical flow(image processing)

Comment: Are you using a library for your project?In my case I was using CImg and I know that CImg can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a drawing library such as this one (native to Java SDK), to draw lines over your image:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

Comment: I think the AWT `Graphics` (or maybe rather `Graphics2D`) classes are not exactly a library, but I agree for drawing some arrows this should be sufficient. And having it in the JDK by default is always a plus.